# Who are the Kaala-Veditha?

Tags: scripture, gods

Who are kaala-veditha? Is this is a class of humans or higher beings or is there a definite source for such information?

Comment: The only occurrence of the phrase Kaala Veditha I can find is in the Nama Ramayana, which [says](http://greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_rama-nama_ramayana.php) "Kaalaa-Vedita-Sura-Pada Raam" which means "I take Refuge in Sri Rama, Who was Made to Know His Divine Position by Kala when His time to depart arrived."  That's a reference to a story I discuss in this answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2111/36 Is that what you're think of?

Comment: @Keshav, I looked at that reference. It is too literal. Isn't there a deeper meaning, such as those who are trapped by time or those who cannot escape time (or era).

Comment: The meaning is really straightforward - Veditha means "made to know".  So Kala-Veditha just means that Rama was informed of it by Kala.  And note that the verses of the Nama Ramayana tell the story of Rama in chronological order, so it's natural that it's in the last Kanda of the Nama Ramayana: http://kksongs.org/songs/a/agatamuniganasamstutarama.html

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if the term you have mentioned is Vedhita or Vidhata so hazarding an attempt to answer the question:

> Kaal means time and Vidhata means organizer/arranger so basically the term refers to the gods of fate and there are two of those - Dhata & Vidhata.

**[Section LXVI of the Sambhava Parva of Mahabharat](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01067.htm)** mentions their origin as follows:

> And Brahman had two other sons, viz., Dhatri and Vidhatri who stayed with Manu. Their sister is the auspicious Lakshmi having her abode amid lotuses.

The **[Bhagvat Purana 1.4.1](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/SrimadBhagavataPurana.html)** also mentions the same:

> Vashishth and his wife Arundhati begot seven Bramarishis like Chitraketu. Sage Atharva and his wife Chitti begot a son Taponishth. Great sage Bhrigu and his wife Khyati begot two sons- **Dhata and Vidhata**, and a daughter- Shri.

**Therefore they are sons of Bhrigu and the grandsons of Brahma.** The **[Mahabharat](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=af1qFbouaVMC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=dhata%20vidhata&source=bl&ots=u0ttDCwX_y&sig=cXtCzMn2CcTdGEq1GF6r7cHODQg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxo6Wk-oHZAhVFwI8KHa-mC6gQ6AEIUzAH#v=onepage&q=dhata%20vidhata&f=false)** mentions them along with Varun as having attained salvation at the banks of Saraswati:

[image]

Again in the section where Jayadratha attempts to abduct Draupadi they are mentioned as divine beings at the level of Indra and Surya:

[image]

Comment: The question is asking something else. The question is about Kala Vedita and not Vidhata. See [comments](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/who-are-the-kaala-veditha#comment14129_7035) under the question.  The OP wants to know the meaning of kalavedita surapada raam which is a part of Nama Ramayanam. He wants to know who is Kalavedita not Vidhata.  So, a irrelevant and not an answer.

Comment: That's why I mentioned am not sure whether the OP is clear of what he is asking. He has asked about a class of beings while the term as mentioned in the comments is just an adjective for Shri Rama.

Comment: but it it is clear he wanted to know who are Kaalaveditas. Whether Kalaveditas are class of beings. The OP responded in the comments that he wanted to know about Kalavedita only not vidhata. If you are not sure, you ask more for clarification and not post an unsure answer. Vidhata and Kalavedita are not the same terms.

Comment: Well he never mentioned that in his comment whether that was really the case. If he responds in the negative I can delete the answer.