# Did Lord Rama ever claim Godhood or divinity himself?

Tags: ramayana, gods, rama

Like Lord Krishna in Mahabharata (geeta) made clear about his divinity, did Rama also show his divine aspect or claim that he was an avatara or god ?
Did he make any claims or statements that he was enlightened or an avatara?

Comment: You may be interested in my Question [Did Rama know that he was Avatar of Lord Vishnu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9188/3500)

Comment: Related [Was Rama a god?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14438/3500).

Answer (score 7):

No, Rāma did not make any such statements. In fact, he [said](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddhasans117.htm#Verse11) quite the opposite:

> **आत्मानं मानुषं मन्ये रामं दशरथात्मजम्** || ६-११७-११ 
>   सोऽहं यस्य यतश्चाहं भगवंस्तद्ब्रवीतु मे |
>
> **ātmānaṃ mānuṣaṃ manye rāmaṃ daśarathātmajam** || 6-117-11 
>   so.ahaṃ yasya yataścāhaṃ bhagavaṃstadbravītu me |
>
> **I think of myself to be a human being, by name Rama, the son of Dasaratha**. You, as a gracious Divinity, tell me that which I as such really am like this.