# What happened to Lord Rama once he went into Sarayu river?

Tags: ramayana, rama

When Lord Rama went to Sarayu river, how did he die? And what happened to his body after that?

I am sorry if my question is offensive, but I'm eager to know.

Comment: Sir sorry but i already know how lord rama attained samadhi...but my question is what happened to them and their bodies and how lord attain samadhi...

Comment: you should see my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/what-is-the-story-of-ramas-death/10097#10097)

Comment: Thank you sir...this litreally got a tear in my eye... Appreciate it well