# What is the reason behind Lord Rama's disappearance?

Tags: ramayana, rama, avatars

I believe Lord Rama is a symbol of Perfect man (as Son, Husband, Father and King), but still I don't know the reason for Rama's disappearance.

According to Padma Purana

> **"Disappearance of Sri Rama from earth happened when he entered voluntarily into the Sarayu River. This divine event is described as the death of Lord Rama. The story of the disappearance of Sri Ram is mentioned in many Hindu scriptures"**.

Any reason behind this?

Comment: Lord vishnu takes avatar only to fulfil pre-planned purpose/duties and when he does complete all his duties (leelayen) for that particular avatar then he has to take his true form (Vishnu form) and get back to Sheer Sagar. And Ram avatar is no exception of it.

Comment: @Rishabh well, but there should is a reason

Comment: To know more in detail you can watch this episode of Ramayan [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WxOwPCItwo),  [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fda21h9JCJc) and [Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1yi_zQscyg). Part one and two is enough for your answer but if you want to know more then you should watch part 3 also.

Comment: @Rishabh do you mean all avatars (God) must have pre-planned duties which had to be done and once it completed, He/she must be disappear. That's what you are saying? . I think these parts are written & directed by current generation. It might be true or not, it won't helpful for me. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Whoever take birth, he/she must have died also some day. So Lord Ram also need to die. Just think about this, if Lord Ram didn't die then how he would come back on earth as Lord Krishna?

Comment: And these parts is not written by our generation, Ramanand Sagar himself told in one of episode that many writers wrote Ramayan but among all those 4 Ramayan script are those who was written by great saints and he is only showing those incidents of Ramayan which are presents in all those 4 scripts, means He is only showing those incident which has been prooven and skipping those which are still in argument. Hence Ramanand Sagar's Ramayan is most trust worthy. And I won't use the word disappear coz they died like all other human, not just vanished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's because his planned time on Earth was over.**. As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2111/36), at the end of Rama's life Yama god of death came to Ayodhya and conveyed a message from the god Brahma.  The message is given in [this chapter](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-117) of the Uttara Kanda of the Ramayana:

> O hero, I am thy son. Thou didst, in thy pristine birth, beget me on Maya I am Kala, the destroyer of all. Lord Brahma, the father of all creatures, has said that thou didst promise to preserve the three worlds.  Formerly when having slain all animals by thy Maya thou wert asleep in the waters of the mighty deep I was born. Thereafter thou didst create the huge bodied Ananta, living in the waters as the king of Nagas. Then thou didst create two highly powerful Asuras named Madhu and Kaitabha.  At that time the bones of those two Asuras having been scattered far and wide this earth containing many mountains was named Medini. Having procreated me in thy lotus navel, dazzling in celestial brilliance thou didst employ me in the work of generation. I took the charge and procreated men; but finding no other means to preserve them I worshipped thee, the lord of the universe and said O lord, thou shouldst protect the creatures, for thou art my father and giver of energy and therefore irrepressible.  Thereupon for concerting means for the preservation of creatures, thou didst renounce thy irrepressible shape and assume Vishnu form. And taking thy birth from Aditi's powerful son, thou wert engaged in enhancing the delight of my brothers. Thou didst use to protect the Devas whenever they were assailed by any calamity.
>
> **O lord of the universe, it is for that reason, on beholding the destruction of creatures thou wert born on earth to slay Dasagriva. And at that time thou didst promise that thou wouldst live in the land of mortals for Eleven thousand years.** Thereupon thou didst assume a human form to carry out thine desire.  Now that period is ripe and this is the proper time to inform thee of it. O great king, do thou wait in this land of mortals if dost thou wish to govern people for some time more. And if dost thou wish to repair to the region of immortals, do thou again lord over the Devas in thy Vishnu form and let them be freed from anxiety.

So he defeated Ravana and ruled for 11000 years as he planned, so now his task on Earth was over.