# Lord Dattatreya's avatar Padvallabh?

Tags: dattatreya, dattaopnishad

Is padvallabh avatar of Lord Dattatreya? Are there any other avatars of Lord Dattatreya? I have heard that there are four avatars. Please give story of them.

Comment: As far as l know, Hindu scripture doesn't mention any incarnations of Dattatreya.  But various medieval and modern Swamis have been considered by their devotees to be incarnations of Dattatreya, including Shirdi Sai Baba.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Do you know in which Hindu scripture Dattatreya himself is mentioned?

Comment: @AADTechnical Yeah, the story of Dattatreya is given in detail in the Markandeya Purana; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1984/36  But he's mentioned in numerous scriptures, including in a lot of the Puranas.  I'm even planning to post a question about him being mentioned in the Brahma Sutras.

Comment: @AADTechnical Here's the question I said I was planning to post, about Dattatreya potentially being mentioned in the Brahma Sutras: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11331/36

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although in your question you mentioned the name as "**padvallabh** "(typo error?) I am assuming it as [Shripad Shri Vallabha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shripad_Shri_Vallabha), who is considered as the **first** avatars (incarnations) of Dattatreya. He was [born](http://www.agnihotrausa.net/Shripad-Shrivallabha.html) in Pithapuram, a town in Godavari district of state Andhra Pradesh in India.

> Are there any other avatars of Lord Dattatreya?

There seems to be different answers for avatars of Lord Dattatreya.

As per "[Shripad Shrivallabha Charitra](http://anaghadattatreyampl.weebly.com/history-of-gurus.html)" Dattatreya have 3 Avataras

1) Shripad Shri Vallabha

2) Narasimha Saraswati

3) Akkalkot Swami Samartha Maharaj.

According to **Wikipedia**, Dattatreya is supposed to have taken **[16 Avatars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dattatreya#As_an_avatar)**.

> Please give story of them.

[Click Here](http://anaghadattatreyampl.weebly.com/history-of-gurus.html) for More information/story about the 3 avataras mentioned in `Shripad Shrivallabha Charitra`

Comment: Thats the most number of avatars accredited to anyone yet

Comment: @AmitSaxena Yes, but unfortunately as per Keshav's comment below Question, there are no scriptures which mentions any incarnations of Dattatreya

Comment: According to Sripada Srivallabha Charitamrutam, even Sri Shirdi Sai Baba is an avatar of Dattatreya, as is Sri Manik Prabhu.