# Books on Datta Sampradaya

Tags: dattatreya

Lord Dattatreya is considered as the united form of trinity i.e. Brahma Vishu Mahesh.There is sect in India which worship him which is called Dattatreya.
Do anybody know good book on Lord Dattatreya in Hindi/English/Marathi.

Comment: Lord Dattatreya is incarnation of Shriman Narayana and other trinity were  Bramha  as Chandra, and Shiva as Durvasa. They were all incarnated to same parents viz Maharishi Atri and his wife Pious Lady Anusyua.http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11331/is-vishnus-incarnation-dattatreya-quoted-in-the-brahma-sutras?r

Comment: @Yogi however who believe in Datta Sampradaya believe that... Lord Datyatreya is Supreme Lord from whom Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh come... and that original Dattatreya incarnated on earth by the same name Dattatreya by the combined form of Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh... This is similar how Ramanandis believe Vishnu is incarnation of Rama and Gaudiyas believe Vishnu is incarnation of Krishna... However this is view of Datta Sampradaya only...

Comment: @Tezz Well both ramanandis and Datta sampradaya people contradict with Shastras viz Valmiki Ramayana and Bhagwad Mahapurana.

Comment: @Yogi Its not only the belief of Datta Sampradaya that he is combined form of trinity but he is also Aaradhya Deva of the Juna Akhada Sanyasis(the oldest section of ascetics in India).

Comment: @ChintaMoney Bhagwad Ramanujacharya and Adi Shankaracharya, Yamunacharya etc these are ancient people, and the asectics order established by them like Shri Rangam sanyasis, Kanchi Kamoti peetham etc are(can be considered as old oreders of vedanta) still running. Anyway it doesn't matter what people believe, only truth matters.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shankaracharya https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujacharya https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamunacharya

Comment: @Yogi Adi Shankaracharya gave Advaita sidhdhanta, Sri Vallbhacharya gave Dvaita sidhdhanta,this is the beauty of our religion, no matter which form you worship believe in that,respect others believe, follow your dharma.This is Sanatan way of life.

Comment: @ChintaMoney Yeah certainly respecting other's belief is the most beautiful part of Hinduism or Sanatan Dharma. But compromising on Shastras is not a way to encompass other's beliefs. Vallabhacharya did not preach Dvaita it was Madhavacharya https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vallabha_Acharya.

Answer (score 5):

"Tripura Rahasya" is an important work on Lord  Dattatreya.There is an Upanishad by name ‘Dattatreya Upanishad'.  When rishis approached God Vishnu for initiation,God Vishnu advised them to recite "I am Datta".  There are several Dattatreya mantras also.The dialogue between Sage Bhargava and Lord Dattareya is known as ‘Tripura Rahasya', the glory of Goddess Tripura.

It is mentioned at this link:-[Is Vishnu's incarnation Dattatreya quoted in the Brahma Sutras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11331/is-vishnus-incarnation-dattatreya-quoted-in-the-brahma-sutras?r)

A copy of Tripura Rahasya is available at this link:- http://www.holybooks.com/tripura-rahasya-mystery-beyond-trinity/

A PDF copy of 'Shri Datta Mahatmya' by Shri Vasudevananda Saraswati Tembe Swami Maharaj is available at this link:-https://archive.org/details/ShriDattaMahatmyaByShrimatPPSadguruShriTembeSwamiMaharaj

A copy of Avadhoota Gita, written  by Sage Dattareya, is also available at this link:-http://www.holybooks.com/the-avadhoota-gita/

Answer (score 3):

**Shree Datta-Sampradai -:**

**Dattatreya or Dattā (दत्त) is a Hindu deity considered to be an avatar (incarnation) of the three Hindu gods Brahma , Vishnu and Shiv collectively known as Trimurthy(त्रिमूर्ती)**.

**Books of Shree Datta- Sampradai-:**

**Shree "GuruCharitra" (श्री. गुरुचरित्र)**  a spiritual book giving a brief life story of Shri 
Narasimha Saraswati Swami ,  **an incarnation of Shri Dattatreya,** 
was written in the 15th Century by one of his closest disciples. This 
book is a treasure house of spiritual events related to the life of Shri
Guru Narasimha Saraswati. **It is read with great reverence by the 
devotees of Lord Shri Dattatreya** [Shree Guru-Charitra गुरु-चरित्र](https://archive.org/details/GuruCharitraMarathi)

Another book on Shree Datta Sampraday is-:**"Avadhut Gita by Dattatreya" (अवधूत गीता)**

The word Avadhuta refers to a mystic who has done away with worldly concerns and standard social etiquette, at least in his or her heart. Avadhuts play a significant role in many Yoga, Vedanta and Bhakti traditions.[Avadhoot Gita अवधूत गीता](http://oaks.nvg.org/avadhut-gita.html)
These books are in Marathi language ,which is mostly spoken in "Maharashtra" state of India.

Comment: I have read Sri Guru Charitra, its on the life story of Sri Nrusimha Saraswati also I know about Sripad Sri Vallabha Charitramrut(श्रीपाद श्रीवल्लभ चरित्रामृत) which is in marathi and gives a brief life story of another incarnation of Sri Dattatreya Sripad Shrivallabh Swami.

Comment: @ChintaMoney - Nice to know that you have gone through the books.Also consider selecting either of the answer as right one.

Comment: @ChintaMoney - sorry the links were not active , I have made the correction in answer. pls follow the links to see both the books. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Today, I was having discussion with my family regarding this topic. Here is the answer what I was seeking it is Datta Mahatmya(दत्त महात्म्य) written by Sri Vasudevananda Saraswati Swami(Tembe Swami) it is translation(marathi) of Datta Puraan again written by Tembe Swami. Tembe Swami collected all the stories related to Lord Datta from different purans and other scriptures and complied it in Datta Puran.

[image: Sri Vasudevananda Saraswati]