# How did the life of Vishwamitra end on this Earth?

Tags: vishwamitra

As of now, I haven't been able to find a proper reference on how the life of Maharishi Vishwamitra, who was Sri Rama's Guru, ended on this Earth. Do any authentic scriptures mention about his life's complete history and when it ended?

Comment: I think he is still alive as one of the Sapta Rishis.

Comment: There are siddhas at end of life in Earth they ended up being in Samadhi. Like wise I am asking how did Vishwamitra life came to an end. I didn't use the word how he passed away. I used the word end. How his duties in Earth came to an end

Comment: completed means how he died or left for other Lokas? @AkshayS

Comment: @Rickross, Yes... how his life ended in Earth... ex: Sri Rama's end -, he ended up his life in Jal Samadhi. In same way, what are instances led to Vishwamitra's stay in Earth to an end and how did he quit his body?

Comment: Vishwamitra is still in his body.  The Saptarishis remain in their bodies, alive and conscious, for the entirety of the Manvantara.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - okay but what happened to his life here in Samsara after Rama period?

Comment: @AkshayS He is still in Samsara.  Just like Devas like Indra remain in their current Janma in Samsara for an entire Manvantara, so do Saptarishis.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan can you post it as answer ?   will give tick mark

Comment: Just one correction he was a Brahma rishi not a Maharishi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such mention in the scriptures that Vishwamitra has ended his life. On the contrary, he is mentioned in several texts as one of the Saptarshis (seven sages) for this manvantara.

> In the present vaivasvata manvantara, the seven great sages are Atri, Vashishtha, Kashyapa, Goutama, Bharadvaja, **Vishvamitra** and Jamadagni. The gods now are the sadhyas, the rudras, the vishvadevas, the vasus, the maruts, the adityas and the two ashvinis. [From *Chapter 3, Manvantaras, Brahma Purana*](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahma-purana/d/doc57554.html)

Vishwamitra is also mentioned asone of the saptarshis in other texts as well.

> kaśyapo ’trir vasiṣṭhaś ca
>   viśvāmitro ’tha gautamaḥ 
>   jamadagnir bharadvāja
>   iti saptarṣayaḥ smṛtāḥ [Srimad Bhagavatam 8.13.5](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/13/5/)
>
> Kaśyapa, Atri, Vasiṣṭha, Viśvāmitra, Gautama, Jamadagni and Bharadvāja are known as the seven sages.

Sapta rishis do not leave this world after this yuga or manvantara. The sages and other beings reach God at the end of the Kalpa and are created again )

> All beings, O Arjuna, enter into My Prakrti at the end of a cycle of time. Again I send these forth at the beginning of a cycle of time. ([Bhagavad Gita 9.7](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=ro&field_chapter_value=9&field_nsutra_value=7&scsh=1&scram=1&scvv=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etradi=1&etadi=1) Translated by Adidevananda)

However, there are some exceptions like chiranjeevis. We do not know if Vishwamitra is a chiranjeevi. So, we can conclude Vishwamitra is still alive and will remain till the end of this kalpa.

Comment: All beings, O Arjuna, enter into My Prakrti at the end of a cycle of time. Again I send these forth at the beginning of a cycle of time. - This could be for the souls which havent attained Moksha?

Comment: Yes. They are baddha jivas trapped in this samsara. It also applies to other beings because even Sun, moon etc., are created every kalpa as a new creation.

Comment: Yes but do we know that same Deva of Sun who was in 1 Kalpa is same in another Kalpa?

Comment: @AkshayS There are 12 adityas for each of 12 months. Each form of sun god will be in respective months. I also wrote answer on saptarshis and adityas. Check that answer. There will be new sun and moon god every kalpa. There is a question about who is current moon i.e., son of atri or Dharma. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18139/5212